# Find $f$ if $f ''' (x) = \sin(x), f(0) = 4, f '(0) = -5, f ''(0) = -9$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure where to begin on this problem. Do you begin by solving the integral of each one then applying the conditions to each respective integral? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{d[f''(x)]}{dx}=\sin x\implies d[f''(x)]=\sin x\ dx$$

Integrating both sides wrt $x,$ to find $f''(x)=-\cos x+C$ where is an arbitrary constant

Now $x=0\implies-9=f''(0)=-\cos0+C\iff C=-8$

Continue this way to find $f(x)$

Comment: I think you mean $-8$.

Comment: @avid19, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate $f'''(x)$, then solve for the constant with the given value of $f''$. Then you repeat until you arrive at $f$.

$$f''(x)=\int f'''(x) \ dx =\int \sin(x) \ dx=-\cos(x) + c_1$$
$$f''(0)=-\cos(0)+c_1=-9$$
$$c_1=-8$$
$$f''(x)=-\cos(x)-8=-\big(\cos(x)+8\big)$$

Now repeat with $f''$.

$$f'(x)=\int f''(x) \  dx = -\int \big(\cos(x)+8\big) \ dx$$

Find $ \ f'$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The key is to realize that the function $$G(x)=b + \int_a^x g(t)\;dt$$ satisfies both $$G'(x)=g(x)$$ and $$G(a)= b.$$